# CSS appearance property - JavaScript half works, half doesn't

Tags: css, properties, appearance

The goal is to make the drop down arrow for a `<select>` list disappear by setting the appearance property using JavaScript.
It:

1. Works for Chrome
2. Does not work for Firefox
3. For Firefox, the drop down arrow can be made to disappear by setting the appearance property in the style section. Whiskey Tango Foxtrot :)

Thanks for any help you can give.

To see the problem,

- Run the page in Chrome. The drop down arrow will not appear. Good,
      the JavaScript line for Chrome lower down on this page does its job
- Run the page in Firefox. The drop down DOES appear. Bad, the 
      comparable JavaScript line for Firefox lower down on this page 
      DOES NOT do its job
- Uncomment the line on CSS and run the page in Firefox. The dropdown will disappear.

```js
//The next line works correctly for Chrome, it makes the drop down arrow disappear    
//document.getElementById("mySelect").style.webkitAppearance = "none";

//The next line does NOT work for Firefox, the drop down arrow STILL appears
document.getElementById("mySelect").style.mozAppearance = "none";
```

```css
select {
  /*-moz-appearance: none; */
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>red</option>
  <option>green</option>
</select>
```

So, for Firefox, why does setting the property in JavaSript not work?

Comment: Your problem here is just a typo:

`mozAppearance` must be `MozAppearance`

Comment: @DaniP has it right. (So their comment should be an answer rather.) However, if the CSS works, why do you need JavaScript at all? I'm not sure why you ran into this problem.